# Ошибка при запуске casperjs

Tags: php, javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Пытаюсь запустить casperjs из кода php:

```
function parser() {
    try {
        echo shell_exec('C:/casperjs/bin/casperjs --version 2>&1');
        flush();
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo('error!');
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}

putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
putenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH");

parser();
```

Из терминала и casperjs и phantomjs запускаются. Из кода php аналогично могу запустить phantomjs --version, но для casperjs выводит ошибку

```
08:38:54Fatal: �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� 䠩�; did you install phantomjs?
```

Уже несколько дней не могу понять, гугление ничего не дало, подскажите куда копать? Система windows8, сервер openserver.

Comment: Неужели никто не может помочь?

Comment: попробуйте для начала изменить кодировку, ведь не понятно какая ошибка, дальше уже будет проще

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, проблема решилась, когда я правильно определил символическую ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

У меня win 7. За другие ОС не ручаюсь.

Я сам себе на этой проблеме все нервы убил, но решение нашел.

И так в папке "**Casperjs**" есть папка "**src**"  в ней файл "**casperjs.cs**", заходим в него и видим на 16-й строке функцию, "**env_varname**" которая возвращает переменную окружения "**PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE**".

Далее идем в "**Переменные среды**" и создаем новую переменную с именем "**PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE**", а путь в моем случае будет "**C:\Phantomjs\bin\phantomjs**".

Удачи тебе и добра =)